# matplotlib type error when trying to plot simple list

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython

If I type this tutorial example into my Spyder IPython console or the editor:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-6209c29ae839>", line 2, in <module>
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4])

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

It makes no sense to me that a list shouldn't be callable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your error. Could you provide any additional information ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the code is ok too. If I try it in the Jupyter console for example it's ok. I must have done something to the Spyder GUI, and I can't figure out what that could have been.

Comment: There is a "Restart kernel" option in the IPython console. After running this it works. Sorry, stupid question, but can't delete it any more.

Comment: You *can* delete a question which does not have any upvoted answers on it.